# Android: safe/smart way to retrieve list of trusted CA?

Tags: android

I am using the below code to retrieve this list.  It seems to work, however it doesn't seem particularly safe/smart because I can't find any documentation that indicates the .bks file will always be available at the hard coded location.

Is this method reasonable, or is there a safer/smarter way to go about this?

```
String filename = "/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks";

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String password = "changeit";
keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keystore);

Iterator it = params.getTrustAnchors().iterator();
//iterate and such
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on the Google group:

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf =  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()); 
tmf.init((KeyStore) null); 
X509TrustManager xtm = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0]; 
for (X509Certificate cert : xtm.getAcceptedIssuers()) { 
    String certStr = "S:" + cert.getSubjectDN().getName() + "\nI:" 
                        + cert.getIssuerDN().getName(); 
    Log.d(TAG, certStr); 
}
```